# Apache Ignite.Net hangs on GetOrCreateCache

Tags: ignite, freeze

I have an Ignite Server running in Java which has a cache as . I am connecting to this server from my C#.Net code using Ignite.Net as a Client node with ClientMode=true. I am able to join the server and also get a list of all caches successfully.

I am trying GetOrCreateCache using multiple ways from my .Net code, but it keeps hanging on that call and never returns:
var cache = ignite.GetOrCreateCache("my-cache");
or
var cache = ignite.GetOrCreateCache("my-cache").WithKeepBinary();

I think I am missing some setting on "Person" that I should do on .Net side, but not sure what. Can someone please help?

Comment: Can you provide logs from all nodes?

Comment: I am looking for them, but from Visual Studio, I don't see much logging. I am not sure how to set the "verbose" option running from Visual Studio.

Comment: You can add "-DIGNITE_QUIET=false" to JvmOptions.

Comment: I could not find a way to set this as I did not have a handle on JVM from Visual Studio. I created my own logger eventually which at least gave a little more details.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone having this issue, I found this: https://dzone.com/articles/building-multi-platform-ignite-cluster-java-net and it started working when I set the Name Mapper as mentioned in that URL.